# PHP optimum file size

Tags: php, performance, file, size

I have a PHP file that is 90 KB.  It pretty much does all the work for the back end on my site and it gets loaded on every page. However, if I split up the different functions in this file and separated them across multiple files, I could reduce the total size of what is loaded on average on each different page to 45 KB.

Is loading a 90 KB PHP file with "everything on it" for each page going to slow the performance of my site down? Does it make more sense to split up the 90 KB file into smaller files and only load what is necessary for each page? Or is 90 KB small enough that it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you talking about the amount of data which is transmitted to the client in the final HTML document? Or the amount of space which your PHP code takes up at-rest on the server's disk? It's not 100% clear. The latter will have almost no bearing on the performance of your site (in fact, having lots of code in one file rather than in lots of separate includes is likely to speed things up, if anything - although on modern hardware it would probably be hard to notice the difference), but the former might.

Comment: Hi ADyson thanks for the clarifying question. Its the amount of space which the PHP code takes up on the server's disk

Comment: 1. Turn on Opcache and PHP will store the pre-processed source in memory and then it doesn't matter. 2. When a file is accessed your OS will usually cache that file in RAM until the memory needs to be reclaimed, and then it doesn't matter. 3. What is in which file is far better classified as an organization problem for a project and its maintainers, and this incredibly marginal performance consideration [say it with me] doesn't matter.

Comment: Great, thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn on Opcache and PHP will store the pre-processed source in memory and then it doesn't matter.
2. When a file is accessed your OS will usually cache that file in RAM until the memory needs to be reclaimed, and then it doesn't matter.
3. What is in which file is far better classified as an organization problem for a project and its maintainers, and this incredibly marginal performance consideration [say it with me] doesn't matter.

Thank you Sammitch from the comments